# mpz_set_str outputting 0 after assigning it to a number

Tags: c++, gmp

It seems very odd that my code doesn't work, I am trying to take input from a user, and assign it to a `mpz_t` for a later calculation, however, just doing a simple test does not give me the expected result.

```
mpz_t n;
mpz_init(n);
const char* num = "25.5";
mpz_set_str(n, num, 10);
mpz_out_str(stdout, 10, n);
printf("\n");
mpz_clear(n);
```

output:

```
0
0
0
0
...
```

Edit:

The return value from the above code is `-1`, which signifies an error, but changing the `num` to be `25` works without any error and prints correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mpz_t` is an integer.  "25.5" is not an integer.  That's why `mpz_set_str()` fails for "25.5" but not for "25" as you pointed out.

`mpf_t` is a floating point value, you can use [`mpf_set_str()`](https://gmplib.org/manual/Assigning-Floats) to set it to "25.5".

Comment: That's the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `mpz` prefix is for integers, it's refusing to process a float string at all, not even the first bit of it like `scanf` would, for example. That's why `"25"` works.